# Will this code allow me to assign a number to a list and incrementally increase the number?

Tags: netlogo

```
 [ set list N = 1 () set list N = 1 
   lput number-of-patches destination origin list N  N + 1]
```

I wish to be able to store information about collections of patches and when the criteria for the filling of the list is met the number of the list will be increased. Will this code work?

Comment: What happens when you try it? It seems you could have done that faster than you could have written and formatted your question here.

Comment: I can,t test this at present because it will produce no visible effect within my program. The purpose of this code is to allow me to calculate the distance of the links between to node patches. This will require the implementation of Dijkstras algorithm to achieve this which will be very complex. I am trying to ask whether the method of incrementing the list will work, it is not possible for me to test it at present.

Comment: Sure it is. Change it temporarily to produce output, and see if it outputs what you need it to in order to test it. You don't have to put it in your actual program - a quick test program would work. If I had to wait for someone at SO to tell me if code I wrote worked or not, I'd never get anything done (and neither would anyone else).

Comment: FYI, NetLogo's [network extension](https://github.com/NetLogo/NW-Extension#readme), which is bundled with NetLogo 5.1, has an implementation of Dijkstra's algorithm, so you should not have to implement this yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Just looking at it, it will give you several syntax errors, regardless of whether the structure will do what you want. For example, the way you should construct a list with element '1' and name 'N' (which is what I think the first line is supposed to do) would be `set N (list 1)`. You can test this by writing code as below and running test (eg by typing test in the command center at the bottom of the interface).

```
globals [N]
to test
  set N (list 1)
  print N
end
```

When writing code, your life is a lot easier if you build up the code in pieces, testing each one as you go either by inspecting agents to see if their property values change as you expect and/or putting print statements in lots of places to see what happens to your variables. This way you are introducing and fixing only a small number of errors in each step. Also, this means you are never writing code that you can't test immediately.

Comment: I'm sorry, I do not want to have a list with N = 1 items but rather a list with three items (number of patches , destination , origin) that will be inserted within the list once each piece of data is available for insertion. The N = 1 represents a means of identification of the list and is incrementally increased (using NN+1) each time the list is created. This will allow me to be able to easily reference the data for a road length within a route finding algorithm by looping through lists and referencing the position of the relevant piece of data so that it can be used within the algorithm.

Comment: Since you responded after Nicolas's comment, I am guessing that you don't want to use the already implemented algorithm in the Network extension for some reason. If this is true, please give an example telling us what you want to call your list (is it N, is it 1 , is is something else?). When you say 'each time the list is created', does that mean you have multiple lists? Or did you mean that a single list has additional items appended (which is what lput does)?